# Shirt Inside Out - Variations

Tags: grammar

How do you say this properly?

1. Your shirt is inside out
2. Your shirt is on wrong side out
3. Your shirt is on the wrong side out
4. Your shirt is wrong side out

My references:

https://www.yourdictionary.com/wrong-side-out

http://say-it-right.com/blog/dont-use-inverted-para-i-englsh-ang-baligtad-ang-suot-na-damit-use-as-we-suggest-here.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are possible, but (3) is less idiomatic, and (1) and (4) don't say that the person is wearing the shirt. Other possibilities are *You've got your shirt on inside out/wrong side out.*

Comment: So idiomatic means natural, right? So I will have to eliminate number 3 then? I am always telling this to my son (he's wearing it) so I have to eliminate 1 and 4 then as well. That leaves me number 2 and the one you have suggested. Did I get it right?

Comment: You _can_ say (1) and (4) when the person is wearing the garment, but  both could also be used of an empty garment.

Comment: Lastly, when a person is wearing the garment, what would you normally use?

Comment: I would use the version I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Kate.